# Get an error when use ruby to send hand coded http request

Tags: ruby, http

Want to test what's going on under the hood of http, so I did something like this:

```
socket = TCPSocket.open('localhost',4567)

request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost\r\n\r\n"

socket.print request
```

But sinatra give me an error:

```
[2012-08-01 14:04:11] ERROR bad Request-Line `'.
ec2-184-169-164-27.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com - - [01/Aug/2012:14:04:11 UTC] "" 400 313
- ->
```

Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried it with just \n instead of \r\n?

Comment: I ran your code successfully against a local sinatra instance. Are you able to use wget or curl to access your sinatra instance succesfully? More information would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This might depend on web server, some web servers **require** some headers (I have had the same problem and solvedit by adding Accept header), and also some firewalls require User-Agent, so try this one:

```
socket.puts "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n"
socket.puts "Host: localhost\r\n"
socket.puts "Accept: text/html,*/*\r\n"
socket.puts "User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (Windows; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 6.0)\r\n"
socket.puts "Connection: close\r\n"
socket.puts "\r\n"
```

also note about space after **:** (it is rare) but a web server might require that!

also using puts might be better than print. (in my opinion!)